# The gold tag badge doesn't show on the mobile version when closing as a duplicate

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, dupehammer

When I vote to close as a duplicate on the regular site it shows the gold badge behind my name:

[image: website]

That does work for the web site, but that doesn't show up in the mobile website:

[image: mobile]

Sample question I closed: [How to create controls dynamically in master's child pages in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30567812/993547).

Can this be fixed please?

(using iPhone 6 on iOS 8.3)

---

The problem still exists, also with the diamond/dupe-hammer combination:

[Here's an example question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268893/change-the-email-address-associated-with-my-stackexchange-account)

Also, when a moderator closes, just a little space after the diamond might improve visibility.

> [image: Sample dupe-hammer closed question]

Comment: Can someone explain the down-vote? Come on, I did test this a million times, cleared the cache obviously...

Comment: +1. Reproduced on Chrome 43.0.2357.78 for Android 5.0.2.

Comment: +1 too. Reproduced on the system browser app (version 4.2.2 - 27) for android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mobile view uses a ● for badges, which I forgot about.

Fixed via css `content`, next to which I've placed a nice `// TODO` for removing the other dozen places it's rendered in server-side code (don't think we had fancy css when this was first created).