# Change the email address associated with my StackExchange account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, email

I log in using a StackExchange account (I don't login with Google, Facebook, or Yahoo).  Is it possible to change the email address associated with my StackExchange account?

If I click on my name at the top of any StackExchange page, I get to my profile page.  Then, clicking on the "my logins" link brings me to a list of my accounts.  There is only one listed:

```
My Logins
Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts

StackExchange
john.doe@domain1.com
```

where `john.doe@domain1.com` is my email address.

What if I want to login instead using `doe.john@domain2.com`?

When I click the "add more logins..." link on the My Logins page, I am prompted to login with StackExchange, Google, Facebook, or Yahoo.  But when I click to login with StackExchange, I am simply redirected to [stackexchange.com](http://www.stackexchange.com) since I am *already* logged in under `john.doe@domain1.com`.  How do I instead associate `doe.john@domain2.com` with my account?

### Update

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102469/302968) says that "You cannot change the e-mail address attached to your openid.stackexchange account, by design."  However, that response was written in 2011.  Is this still the case?

Also, comments to [that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102469/302968) suggest that there is some sort of "swap" feature.  Does that still exist?

Comment: There is a write up from [Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704)