# Gold tag badge icon missing on mobile web

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

On questions that get closed by the dupe-hammer, the fold tags badge doesn't show up nicely inside its box on the mobile site.

[Here's an example question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268893/change-the-email-address-associated-with-my-stackexchange-account)

Also, when a moderator closes, just a little space after the diamond might improve visibility.

> [image: Sample dupe-hammer closed question]

Comment: Oops, I see [you told us about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257575/the-gold-tag-badge-doesnt-show-on-the-mobile-version-when-closing-as-a-duplicat) before - gotta get a designer to add images to the mobile sprite.  Doing that now.

Comment: Well that is fun. Didn't remember it any more. Thanks.