# Gold tag badge icon missing in post notice on mobile web

Tags: bug, mobile-web, dupehammer, regression

Gold tag badge is missing in the post notices on mobile web view. [Post reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340749/312043)

Screenshot for reference:

> [image]

Comment: Have you tried reloading it?

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica doesn't help. I don't see it either, and it's my own badge ...

Comment: The same kind of bug was reported for old post notice and was [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257575/312043)